# How to Populate div input form field value with variable

Tags: html

Is there a way to fill an input field with a variable. I think something like this:

<input id="email2" name="email2" value>

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Are you asking if you want your input field auto populate a preset value when loading? Or, only populate a certain value from a user action using a variable?

Comment: @BrentHarris. Want input field auto populate a preset value when loading. I mean without using Javascript. I can do it with the onLoad function. Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to present with actual value, use value attribute and set it to what you want. If you just want placeholder text or number that shows up but doesnt actually have any value, use the placeholder attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

        <input id="email2" value="2345">
        
        <!-- OR -->
        
        <input id="email3" placeholder="123">
        


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll explain what i need:
When calling the html page, i'll send a text (message). I want to put this message into a text input field:
JavaScript
var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page1');
htmlOutput.message = 'Hello';
return htmlOutput.evaluate();

HTML:
<input type="text" id="text1" value = message>